# Problems with making Silverlight project out of browser

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I have a task to make large Silverlight project run out of browser.

Fortunatelly I don't have to rewrite it to some other technology. Unfortunatelly I can not understand how to make it work OOB. I tried everything that's in guides :

enabling OOB option, installing and tryiung to debug installed app, but main thing is that when I run this app OOB I can't reach any services (no matter how I try HTML Bridge is disabled in OOB).

Is there a way to reach those services (like https://localhost/WCFRest/GetUserInfo?login=somelogin&password=somepassword) from OOB enviroment?

What should I do to reach them?

I'm sorry if this is noob quetion but I can't ask anyone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have a Web project in your solution. I think you changed the startup project to the silverlight project. You need to start up the Web project too.

Do the following:

1. Right click on the solution in the Solution Explorer and select Properties.
2. Select "Multiple startup projects" and set the action to "Start" (on the web project)

Or just simply right click on a HTML or ASPX file in the web project and select "View in Browser".